# Powershell adding random symbols to registry value?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that adds a string value at a location:

```
Push-Location
Set-Location HKCU:
New-ItemProperty  -Path  
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Security\Crypto\EscrowCerts -Name 
"EscrowCert01" -Value '‎02 ee 7f'  -PropertyType "String"
```

It works, the value is added. However, three symbols have been added to the start of the string.

[image: Unwanted Symbols]

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: FYI: Your code worked for me.  Is there any value already defined in that location?  Are you certain the spaces are real spaces (i.e. sometimes other whitespace or "invisible" characters can hide unseen); this often happens when copy-pasting content from the web; e.g. non-breaking spaces (ascii 255) are often used in place of regular (ascii 32) spaces.

Comment: please copy the text and check its real codepoints, an [image doesn't help here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: ps. you mentioned that 3 characters are added to the start (`â€ž`); are you concerned by those on the end (` a9 8e 7f ab e3`)?

Comment: pps. That character sequence (`â€ž`) shows up here: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html; i.e. it can be a corruption of the UTF8 character `„` if the wrong encoding is used.  Is the above code the exact code you're running / have you confirmed that running exactly that code causes an issue, or is this an attempt to summarise the line of code which you believe caused the issue (i.e. potentially you could be reading the value from a file, but have removed that from the posted example to simplify your question; not realising that the error no longer occurs with the new code).

Comment: The code above is what I am running, however, I have removed additional characters from the value just to simplify. I have checked to make sure that the spaces are real spaces and still get the same result. If the code worked for you maybe it does point to UTF8 corruption?